# How to import a .bas file into excel by using .vbs

Tags: excel, vba

What I'd like to do is:

- By using a .vbs file opening an excel file
- importing a .bas file to that file (automatically, by using code)
- run the particular sub that I wrote in that .bas file (VGEL is the name of the sub)
- Close the excel file

All the processes must be done by using the code. I share the code of .vbs file. Can anyone help me about it? Please....

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ali.kirikci\Desktop\Cross Rate\CrossRate.xlsm",TRUE)

objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\ali.kirikci\Desktop\Cross Rate\CrossRate.xlsm'!Module12.VGEL"

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

objExcel.Application.Quit

Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Without creating a file to test, this looks like it should work. Does it not currently?

Comment: may as well pop it into the "answer" box below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! I'm sharing this, because someone may get help from it:
objExcel.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import "C:\Users...\Desktop\ModuleName\ModuleName.bas"